Xcode crash during app validation, NSInvalidArgumentException
I don't undertand why now I can't validate my app. All work great serveral weeks ago, but now it crash. Here is a part of my log
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [1538]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               15.2 (22503)
Build Info:            IDEApplication-22503000000000000~3 (15C500b)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       862131722
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-06-28 18:52:09.4023 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 13.5 (22G74)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        C7466B64-E1D2-AB6A-6A71-E4C1DCB8061C


Time Awake Since Boot: 1100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: archive info plist lock

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   Xcode [1538]

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
com.apple.main-thread


Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException

Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001956e3154 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
1   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c11a04 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 388
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001952024d4 objc_exception_throw + 60
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001957cd9b8 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001957dac10 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithCapacity:].cold.1 + 0
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001955f6ae0 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 320
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001955f6974 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 52
7   IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fcbf04 -[IDEArchiveDistributionRecord dictionaryRepresentation] + 296
8   IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fad4cc __31-[IDEArchive setDistributions:]_block_invoke + 16
9   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c09700 -[NSArray(DVTFoundationClassAdditions) dvt_arrayByApplyingBlock:] + 224
10  IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fad45c -[IDEArchive setDistributions:] + 84
11  Foundation                          0x00000001965aad94 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] + 604
12  Foundation                          0x00000001965d4f00 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 64
13  Foundation                          0x00000001965ee42c _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 284
14  IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fad254 __36-[IDEArchive addDistribution:error:]_block_invoke + 156
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001953dc400 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001953eb97c _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
17  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c55d54 DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 148
18  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c31e88 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 60
19  IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fad07c -[IDEArchive addDistribution:error:] + 200
20  IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106f534ac __41-[IDEDistributionValidationStep validate]_block_invoke + 116
21  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c55070 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
22  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c55848 __DVTSyncPerformBlock_block_invoke + 68
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019566a1d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 28
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019566a0e8 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 364
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019566958c __CFRunLoopRun + 2432
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
27  HIToolbox                           0x000000019eebadf0 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
28  HIToolbox                           0x000000019eebac2c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 648
29  HIToolbox                           0x000000019eeba984 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
30  AppKit                              0x000000019888f97c _DPSNextEvent + 636
31  AppKit                              0x000000019888eb18 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 716
32  DVTKit                              0x00000001014cf26c -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 300
33  AppKit                              0x0000000198882f7c -[NSApplication run] + 464
34  DVTKit                              0x00000001014ce538 -[DVTApplication run] + 60
35  AppKit                              0x000000019885a3cc NSApplicationMain + 880
36  dyld                                0x0000000195233f28 start + 2236
Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001956e3154 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
1   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c11a04 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 388
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001952024d4 objc_exception_throw + 60
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001957cd9b8 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001957dac10 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithCapacity:].cold.1 + 0
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001955f6ae0 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 320
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001955f6974 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 52
7   IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fcbf04 -[IDEArchiveDistributionRecord dictionaryRepresentation] + 296
8   IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fad4cc __31-[IDEArchive setDistributions:]_block_invoke + 16
9   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c09700 -[NSArray(DVTFoundationClassAdditions) dvt_arrayByApplyingBlock:] + 224
10  IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fad45c -[IDEArchive setDistributions:] + 84
11  Foundation                          0x00000001965aad94 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] + 604
12  Foundation                          0x00000001965d4f00 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 64
13  Foundation                          0x00000001965ee42c _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 284
14  IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fad254 __36-[IDEArchive addDistribution:error:]_block_invoke + 156
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001953dc400 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001953eb97c _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
17  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c55d54 DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 148
18  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c31e88 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 60
19  IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106fad07c -[IDEArchive addDistribution:error:] + 200
20  IDEFoundation                       0x0000000106f534ac __41-[IDEDistributionValidationStep validate]_block_invoke + 116
21  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c55070 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
22  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100c55848 __DVTSyncPerformBlock_block_invoke + 68
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019566a1d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 28
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019566a0e8 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 364
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019566958c __CFRunLoopRun + 2432
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
27  HIToolbox                           0x000000019eebadf0 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
28  HIToolbox                           0x000000019eebac2c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 648
29  HIToolbox                           0x000000019eeba984 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
30  AppKit                              0x000000019888f97c _DPSNextEvent + 636
31  AppKit                              0x000000019888eb18 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 716
32  DVTKit                              0x00000001014cf26c -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 300
33  AppKit                              0x0000000198882f7c -[NSApplication run] + 464
34  DVTKit                              0x00000001014ce538 -[DVTApplication run] + 60
35  AppKit                              0x000000019885a3cc NSApplicationMain + 880
36  dyld                                0x0000000195233f28 start + 2236


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: archive info plist lock
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x195554764 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19558bc28 pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x195499ae8 abort + 180
3   IDEKit                                 0x1053bacbc +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 972
4   IDEKit                                 0x1053bbdec -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 596
5   IDEKit                                 0x1053bc11c IDEHandleUncaughtException + 68
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1957810c4 __handleUncaughtException + 692
7   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19520b020 _objc_terminate() + 132
8   libc++abi.dylib                        0x195543f48 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
9   libc++abi.dylib                        0x195543eec std::terminate() + 56
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1953dc414 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1953eb97c _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
12  DVTFoundation                          0x100c55d54 DVTDispatchBarrierSync + 148
13  DVTFoundation                          0x100c31e88 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 60
14  IDEFoundation                          0x106fad07c -[IDEArchive addDistribution:error:] + 200
15  IDEFoundation                          0x106f534ac __41-[IDEDistributionValidationStep validate]_block_invoke + 116
16  DVTFoundation                          0x100c55070 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
17  DVTFoundation                          0x100c55848 __DVTSyncPerformBlock_block_invoke + 68
18  CoreFoundation                         0x19566a1d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 28
19  CoreFoundation                         0x19566a0e8 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 364
20  CoreFoundation                         0x19566958c __CFRunLoopRun + 2432
21  CoreFoundation                         0x1956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
22  HIToolbox                              0x19eebadf0 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
23  HIToolbox                              0x19eebac2c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 648
24  HIToolbox                              0x19eeba984 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
25  AppKit                                 0x19888f97c _DPSNextEvent + 636
26  AppKit                                 0x19888eb18 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 716
27  DVTKit                                 0x1014cf26c -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 300
28  AppKit                                 0x198882f7c -[NSApplication run] + 464
29  DVTKit                                 0x1014ce538 -[DVTApplication run] + 60
30  AppKit                                 0x19885a3cc NSApplicationMain + 880
31  dyld                                   0x195233f28 start + 2236

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554bf54 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19555e280 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x195554bb8 mach_msg_overwrite + 604
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554c2d0 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19566a7e4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1956690c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   Foundation                             0x1965e1fbc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   DTDeviceKitBase                        0x10d5f338c +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 148
9   Foundation                             0x1965db53c __NSThread__start__ + 716
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19558bfa8 _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586da0 thread_start + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554bf54 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19555e280 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x195554bb8 mach_msg_overwrite + 604
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554c2d0 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19566a7e4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1956690c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   Foundation                             0x1965e1fbc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   DTDeviceKitBase                        0x10d5fe758 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 228
9   Foundation                             0x1965db53c __NSThread__start__ + 716
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19558bfa8 _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586da0 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x195557030 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                         0x19569416c __CFSocketManager + 636
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19558bfa8 _pthread_start + 148
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586da0 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554bf54 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19555e280 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x195554bb8 mach_msg_overwrite + 604
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554c2d0 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19566a7e4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1956690c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   AppKit                                 0x1989b9f54 _NSEventThread + 172
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19558bfa8 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586da0 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554bf54 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19555e280 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x195554bb8 mach_msg_overwrite + 604
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554c2d0 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19566a7e4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1956690c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   Foundation                             0x1965e1fbc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x19665acbc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 64
9   GPUToolsMobileFoundation               0x2ba4c1100 -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 140
10  Foundation                             0x1965db53c __NSThread__start__ + 716
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19558bfa8 _pthread_start + 148
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586da0 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554bf54 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19555e280 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x195554bb8 mach_msg_overwrite + 604
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554c2d0 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19566a7e4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1956690c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   CFNetwork                              0x19a04ed28 0x199dfb000 + 2440488
8   Foundation                             0x1965db53c __NSThread__start__ + 716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19558bfa8 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586da0 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554bf54 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19555e280 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x195554bb8 mach_msg_overwrite + 604
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554c2d0 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19566a7e4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1956690c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1956ed57c CFRunLoopRun + 64
8   SwiftPM                                0x2c448ef00 closure #1 in FSEventStream.start() + 224
9   SwiftPM                                0x2c445f0e4 closure #1 in Thread.init(task:) + 120
10  SwiftPM                                0x2c445ee90 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28
11  SwiftPM                                0x2c445f250 @objc ThreadImpl.main() + 44
12  Foundation                             0x1965db53c __NSThread__start__ + 716
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19558bfa8 _pthread_start + 148
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586da0 thread_start + 8

Thread 8::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554bed0 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1953dc99c _dispatch_sema4_wait + 28
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1953dd050 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 132
3   DVTFoundation                          0x100c556d0 DVTSyncPerformBlock + 320
4   IDEFoundation                          0x106f53330 -[IDEDistributionValidationStep validate] + 1840
5   IDEFoundation                          0x106f53548 -[IDEDistributionValidationStep loadDrivableFromExportOptions:error:] + 20
6   IDEFoundation                          0x106ddbeb4 -[IDEDistributionDriver runWithDestinationPath:wantsExportStep:] + 1992
7   IDEFoundation                          0x1070917ec closure #1 in RecoverableDistributionDriver.run() + 188
8   IDEFoundation                          0x10702d2c4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable () -> () + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1953da874 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1953dc400 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1953df4e0 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 788
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1953ede98 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1953ee6c0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195588038 _pthread_wqthread + 228
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586d94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554bf54 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19555e280 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x195554bb8 mach_msg_overwrite + 604
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19554c2d0 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19566a7e4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1956690c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1956684b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1956ed57c CFRunLoopRun + 64
8   DebugSymbolsDT                         0x1008f43bc SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 580
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19558bfa8 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x195586da0 thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000000000029   x6: 0x0000000000004400   x7: 0x000000016f65d158
    x8: 0xa4ac1ce7c601189e   x9: 0xa4ac1ce63661f81e  x10: 0x000060000f8834df  x11: 0x000000000000000f
   x12: 0x000000000000000f  x13: 0x000060001bd790e0  x14: 0x01000001f0b2b195  x15: 0x00000001f0b2b190
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001f51333a0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001f060e080  x21: 0x0000000000000103  x22: 0x00000001f060e160  x23: 0x000060001532c660
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000060000156c280  x27: 0x0000600000069a00
   x28: 0x00000001f060f9a0   fp: 0x000000016f65dd60   lr: 0x000000019558bc28
    sp: 0x000000016f65dd40   pc: 0x0000000195554764 cpsr: 0x40001000
   far: 0x00000002d5151c08  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x1007a0000 -        0x1007a3fff com.apple.dt.Xcode (15.2) <ca976695-3a67-3f28-b6ee-6a58d541a7a8> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x1018ac000 -        0x101d43fff com.apple.MIL (5.33) <7e15092b-8052-35db-a2b9-df83e1194152> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SystemFrameworks/MIL.framework/Versions/A/MIL
       0x1008c8000 -        0x1008cbfff libIDEApplicationLoader.dylib (*) <f608c6c5-9acc-3ce4-8a8d-d7c936be4861> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libIDEApplicationLoader.dylib
       0x1009b8000 -        0x1009ebfff com.apple.dt.DVTCocoaAdditionsKit (15.2) <b4143b5c-3930-33b5-bb01-84f09ef932be> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTCocoaAdditionsKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTCocoaAdditionsKit
       0x100a28000 -        0x101083fff com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (15.2) <de3c44fb-0e62-34ed-a361-552a9461f2e9> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
       0x1014bc000 -        0x101633fff com.apple.dt.DVTKit (15.2) <5520cf5b-7ac1-34f4-b667-9cb34aca9b3b> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
       0x1052d0000 -        0x105e8ffff com.apple.dt.IDEKit (15.2) <0977f08d-10b1-3514-978d-72119ddc0f15> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
       0x106bd8000 -        0x1075b3fff com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation (15.2) <270ff38e-661a-3a86-82d0-7c32dc86a21e> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
       0x103570000 -        0x103b83fff com.apple.SceneKit (1.0) <f115b83b-e8a2-3cee-bc36-f2f8ea74b35f> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SystemFrameworks/SceneKit.framework/Versions/A/SceneKit
       0x102110000 -        0x102babfff com.apple.ModelIO (265.101.7) <8224d6ae-8c7c-36c9-9f12-b8733eaedbca> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SystemFrameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO
       0x1008dc000 -        0x1008dffff com.apple.USDLib_FormatLoaderProxy (1.0) <d926ab90-7ceb-3721-8675-5b84d83e0f71> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/USDLib_FormatLoaderProxy_Xcode.framework/Versions/A/USDLib_FormatLoaderProxy_Xcode
       0x10329c000 -        0x1033cbfff com.apple.dt.MLAssetIO (1.0) <0f8624ab-cdfe-37c7-b8c8-c16d78b81a86> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SystemFrameworks/MLAssetIO.framework/Versions/A/MLAssetIO
       0x103fec000 -        0x1041c3fff com.apple.mlcompiler.runtime (*) <8c9a14d4-9aef-3b8f-9d8e-6cbcae87c416> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MLCompilerRuntime.framework/Versions/A/MLCompilerRuntime


This issue is generally arise due to The program license agreement update on apple.
Go to this link and login with developer account :  Apple Developer
Then check for The program license agreement has been updated. section asking to agree by account holder. Once agreed and accepted latest license agreement, this error will be resolved.
Crash must be an issue from the apple and xcode should not crash, but this crash is a result of above issue.

Assuming you haven't updated Xcode in the time since you were able to successfully validate, I'd start to figure this out by going back to the version of your app that you successfully validated. If Xcode can validate that without crashing, then you might reasonably suspect that whatever is causing Xcode to crash was added since then. You could then start adding commits one at a time until Xcode starts to crash, at which point you'll have found the commit that causes the problem.
If you've updated the version of Xcode you're using since the last time you successfully validated, go back to the previous version of Xcode. (All the versions are available to download from Apple's developer site, so you can go back even if you normally install Xcode via the App Store.)
Either way, you should also report this crash to Apple if you haven't already. Ideally, Xcode shouldn't crash no matter what kind of code you throw at it. Your app might crash, of course, but Xcode itself shouldn't.

Thank you for the reply, I tried to downgrade to 2023 to be sur, but I have the same crash :(

And if you go back to the version of your code that you successfully validated in the past?

ok, the problem come from document agreement .. -_-
